solving powell badly scaled test function using conjugate gradient method
I am trying to solve the powell bad scaled test function, which and its gradient function are given below:
function f = fun(X)
    x = X(1);
    y = X(2);
    f1 = 1e4 * x * y - 1;
    f2 = exp(-x) + exp(-y) - 1.0001;
    f= f1^2 + f2^2;
end

function g = grid(X)
    x = X(1);
    y = X(2);
    f1 = 1e4 * x * y - 1;
    f2 = exp(-x) + exp(-y) - 1.0001;
    g1 = 2 * f1 * 1e4 * y - 2 * f2 * exp(-x);
    g2 = 2 * f1 * 1e4 * x - 2 * f2 * exp(-y);
    g = [g1; g2];
end

The following are the PRP conjugate gradient method, the standard Wolfe step size criterion, and the final running code:
function [x,val,k]=frcg1(fun,grid,x0)
k=0;
maxk=10000;
e=1e-5;
n=length(x0);
while(k<maxk)
    g=feval(grid,x0);
    itern=k-(n+1)*floor(k/(n+1));
     itern=itern+1;
       if(itern==1)
           d=-g;
       else
           %beta=(g'*g)/(g0'*g0);
           beta = (g' * (g - g0)) / (g0' * g0);
           %d=-g+beta*d0;
            d=-(1 + beta*(g' *d0)/(g'* g) )*g+beta*d0;
           gd=g'*d; 
           if(gd>=0.0)
               d=-g;
           end
       end
    if(norm(g)<=e) ,break;end
     alpha = Wolfe2(fun, grid, x0, d);
     x0=x0+d*alpha ;
     val=feval(fun,x0);
     g0=g;
     d0=d;
     k=k+1;
end
x=x0;
val=feval(fun,x);
end


function [alpha, xk, f, k] = Wolfe2(fun, grid, x0, dk)
    c1 = 0.03; c2 = 0.3; % 0 < c1 < c2 < 1
    alpha = 1;  
    k = 0;      
    a = 0; b = inf; 
    g0 = feval(grid, x0);   
    fk = feval(fun, x0 + alpha * dk);   
    gk = feval(grid, x0 + alpha * dk);  
    l = feval(fun, x0) + c1 * alpha * g0' * dk;     % Armjio
    while true
        if fk > l
            k = k + 1;
            b = alpha;
            alpha = (a + b) / 2;
            fk = feval(fun, x0 + alpha * dk);
            l = feval(fun, x0) + c1 * alpha * g0' * dk;
            gk = feval(grid, x0 + alpha * dk);
            continue;
        end
        if gk' * dk < c2 * g0' * dk % Wolfe
            k = k + 1;
            a = alpha;
            alpha = min([2 * alpha, (a + b) / 2]);
            fk = feval(fun, x0 + alpha * dk);
            l = feval(fun, x0) + c1 * alpha * g0' * dk;
            gk = feval(grid, x0 + alpha * dk);
            continue;
        end
        break;
    end
    xk = x0 + alpha * dk;   
    f = feval(fun, xk);    
end


clc;
clear;
x0 = [0 1]';
tic;
[x,f,k]=frcg1(@fun,@grid,x0)
total_time = toc;
disp(num2str(total_time), 's');

I want to know where the problem lies with my Matlab code? The result I obtained deviated from the correct value. And no matter how maxk is modified, the final value of k obtained is equal to maxk. Here are the results I obtained from running：
x = 
 
0.0000 
2.2818 
 
 
f = 
 
0.0104 
 
 
k = 
 
10000

The correct numerical result should be:
x =  

1.098e-5 
9.106…… 
 
f = 
0

